# Getting seg fault when assigning random float value in a loop from rand()

Tags: c, random

I cannot figure out why my code works only one way and it is driving me crazy because it just should work.Whole code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAGIC_CONSTANT 73.

int Check_Parameters(int argc, char **argv){
    int i=0;

    if(argc > 3){
        printf("You have entered more than 2 arguments!\n");
    }

    do{ 
        if(isdigit(argv[2][i]) == 0){
            printf("Second argument should be number!\n");

            return 0;
        }

        i++;
    }while(argv[2][i] != 0);

    return 1;
}

int Write_Sequence(char **argv,int Handle){
    char *length;
    float *values,help;
    unsigned int i,j,index;

    index = atoi(argv[2]);

    for(i=0; i<index; i++){
        *length = (char)(rand()%11+10);

        if(write(Handle,length,1) == -1){
            printf("Something went wrong during Index writing\n%s\n",strerror(errno));

            return 0;
        }

        printf("Value is: %u\n",*(unsigned int *)length);

        values = malloc(*length*sizeof(float));

        if(values == NULL){
            printf("Memory allocation for values failed\n");

            return 0;
        };

        for(j=0; j<*length; j++){
             help = (rand()%200)/MAGIC_CONSTANT;
             values[j] = (float)(rand()%200)/MAGIC_CONSTANT;
             printf("%lf\n",values[j]); 

        }

        if(write(Handle,(char*)values,sizeof(float)*(*length)) == -1){
            printf("Something went wrong during value writing\n%s\n",strerror(errno));

            return 0;
        };

        free(values);
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int Handle;
    char *citaj;

    srand(time(NULL));
    Check_Parameters(argc,argv);    

    Handle = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    Write_Sequence(argv,Handle);

    close(Handle);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to fill my allocated memory with floats. The thing is that this code does not work:

```
 for(j=0; j<*length; j++){
                 values[j] = (rand()%200)/MAGIC_CONSTANT;   
        }
```

But this one does without any problem:

```
for(j=0; j<*length; j++){
             help = (rand()%200)/MAGIC_CONSTANT;
             values[j] = help;
}
```

MAGIC_CONSTANT = 73.

The thing is it only works when I first assign it to my help variable and then to the memory and whenever I assign it right away it gives me segmentation fault. What is wrong with that rand() function?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. How is `values` declared / allocated / defined?

Comment: The problem is not in this code - please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: char *length;
 float *values,help;
 unsigned int i,j,index;

Comment: I did not include the whole code just cause I made it work with "help" variable so there is not problem with intervals or anything. Also I changed *length to 10 or any number just to be sure and it still did not work.

Comment: ...you havent assigned the array values to a size...

also, make sure to edit your original post to include those declarations

Comment: Please edit the extra information into your question, showing how the variables are set (or using dummy assignments to achieve the same result).  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — that's the same link Oliver referred you to.

Comment: @NickMeyer ... as suspected...

Comment: one is trying to store the value directly, the other is storing the pointer to the value.

Comment: You assign to `*length` but not to `length`.  You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^ storing '(char)(rand()%11+10)' at some unknown location - UB :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `length` as a `char *`, but you never give it a value.  You then try to dereference the pointer by assigning to `*length`.  That invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In your case, this manifests as a segfault in your code without `help` but appears to work when you do use `help`.

In this code, you don't need `length` to be a pointer.  Instead, declare it as a `char` and assign to it directly.  Then when calling `write`, take its address.

```
int Write_Sequence(char **argv,int Handle){
    // declare as char
    char length;
    float *values,help;
    unsigned int i,j,index;

    index = atoi(argv[2]);

    for(i=0; i<index; i++){
        // assign directly to length
        length = (char)(rand()%11+10);

        // pass address of length to write
        if(write(Handle,&length,1) == -1){
            printf("Something went wrong during Index writing\n%s\n",strerror(errno));

            return 0;
        }
        ...
```

Comment: YES YEEES it works. I just thought for some reason when I declared the pointer that I have space for one char as well. Damn me. THANK YOU ALL

Comment: _undefined behavior_ as described is the central issue, and answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
*length = (char)(rand()%11+10);
```

You are attempting to assign the type-casted output of `rand()` into an uninitialized pointer.  I am not sure what you intended to use this for, but if your compiler is set properly, this should throw warnings. (uninitialized pointer)

Other things to consider, 1) for how its used, `length` does not need to be a pointer.  2) when using `rand()`, it is recommended that `srand()` be called first to `seed` the pseudo randomizer `rand()`.  Once you do these few things, your code at least starts to work. There are other things you can do to optimize, but a code segment with these changes is below.

```
#define MAGIC_CONSTANT 73

int main(void)
{

    char length = 0;
    float *values,help;
    unsigned int i,j;

    srand(clock());

    length = (char)(rand()%11+10);
    values = malloc(length*sizeof(float));  

    for(j=0; j<length; j++)
    {
      values[j] = (rand()%200)/MAGIC_CONSTANT;   
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yea well, it has to be pointer because I am also writing that value to a file using write(). Also I have srand(time(NULL)) in my main function. I just posted code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: if you need to send a pointer, then send it's address:  `&length`,  But the way it is being used, it can be an `int`, or `char`.

Comment: @ligazetom You don't need `length` to be a pointer just for that.  Declare it as `char length;` then call `write(fd, &length, 1)`

Comment: @dbush thats actually pretty good, anyway :D it is not really problem though

Comment: @ligazetom Actually, it is.  See my answer.

Comment: @ryyker omg I wasn't coding for SO LONG I am DUMB AF. I finally get what you are saying about that length. -_- ..still not sure if it will help with my original problem but that is one thing to consider!! thanks

Comment: @ligazetom - thanks for the accept, but dbush's answer hits the mark with _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: @ryyker yea but I got it when I read you answer, however I dont really mind :) points are points. Once again, thank you guys. Always something stupid like this. The thing is it did not work even when I changed the *length to number 10. Thats why I didn't care about that . Strange. Anyway have a nice day

Comment: @ligazetom - glad to help!  When you get some time, Google `undefined behavior`. It is a simple, but very important concept.  C allows us to do things (without notification) that we ought not do.